# Is it always possible to factor an element that is not irreducible into two non-units?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

A book I am reading defines irreducible elements of an integral domain $D$ as follows:

> A nonzero element  $a\in D$ is called an irreducible if $a$ is not a unit and, whenever $b$, $c \in D$ with $a=bc$, then $b$ or $c$ is a unit.

In a proof following this definition, the author writes:

> If $a$ is irreducible, we are done. Thus, we may assume that $a = bc$, where neither $b$ nor $c$ is a unit and $c$ is nonzero.

My question is:

Is a factorisation of an element which is *not* irreducible (here, $a$ with $a=bc$) always guaranteed?

Obviously, if such a factorisation exists, then neither $b$ nor $c$ can be units (else this would contradict the non-irreducibility of $a$).

I have read this post: [Reducible element of ring can be factorized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681450/reducible-element-of-ring-can-be-factorized), however it hasn't helped.

Help!

Comment: Factorization is always guaranteed in a ring with identity. $x = 1 \cdot x$. If $x$ is reducible however, this is *precisely* that $x$ has an interesting factorization.

Comment: @DuncanRamage thanks for the answer, I understand that a factorisation is guaranteed. The identity element is a unit though, and if $a$ is reducible with $a=bc$, then neither $b$ nor $c$ can be units (so $b$ and $c$ can't be $1$), so the 'trivial' factorisation doesn't count. Pardon if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, the negation of the definition of irreducible says that $\,a \neq 0\,$ is not irreducible if $a$ is a unit or $\,a = bc\,$ for some nonunits $\,b,c\ \ $

Comment: @DuncanRamage To elaborate: I can't see how negating the definition of 'irreducible element' says that a reducible element must necessarily have a factorisation. (If the factorisation exists, then clearly it must be 'interesting' in the sense that none of the factors can be units)

Comment: @BillDubuque Ohh I see now! Thank you!

Comment: $$\begin{align} \lnot\, [\forall b,c\!:\ &a= bc\Rightarrow\, b\mid 1\ \lor\, c\mid 1]\\[.1em]  
\equiv\, \exists b,c\!:\ &a= bc\ \land\ b\nmid 1\ \land\, c\nmid 1 \end{align}$$